# Код не работает для всех заглавных букв в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Напишите программу Python, чтобы найти последовательности одной буквы верхнего регистра, за которой следуют буквы нижнего регистра. Если данное условие выполняется, то выведите Found a match!, иначе Not matched!

```
import re
def text_match(text):
        patterns ='^[A-Z]+_[a-z]+$'
        if not re.search(patterns,  text):
                return 'Found a match!'
        else:
                return('Not matched!')
print(text_match(input()))
```

Comment: Добавьте примеры, при которых ваш код не работает как задумано

Comment: Например при вводе xdkvjhFcdhk - верно, а при JHFVNKJ - должен выдавать Not matched!, а выдаёт Found a match!

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно в это сторону было идти: https://regex101.com/r/X1A2pI/1, т.к. `последовательности одной буквы верхнего регистра`, т.е. `AAA`, а вот `ABC` уже не подходит

Comment: Очень сложное объяснение того, что нужно, попробовал вас понять, попробуйте `(?=\b[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]+\b).*`

Comment: похоже у вас просто return'ы местами перепутаны

Comment: Всем спасибо большое за советы! Справилась) Нужно было сделать так  import re
def text_match(text):
        patterns ='[A-Z]+[a-z]+$'
        if re.search(patterns,  text):
                return 'Found a match!'
        else:
                return('Not matched!')
print(text_match(input()))

Comment: @Yana, вы молодец, что разобрались :) Оформите, пожалуйста, самостоятельно ответ с вашим решением и примите его :)